# Angularjs binding does not work when injecting html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to look at [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)   but it seems i am missing something. I am trying to inject html which is bound to a json. It works fine if the html is declared but when i inject it despite calling the $compile it is not working. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js">        </script>
 <script src="todo.js"></script>
<script> 

 function TodoCtrl($scope)
  {
  $scope.todos = [{text:'LearnAngularJS'}, {text:'Unlearn Angular'},];
 }

 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 $('#div1').html(
$compile('<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl"><ul><li ng-repeat="todo in todos"    compile="text">{{todo.text}}<li><ul><div>')(scope));
 });

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
  {{todo.text}}
   <li>
  <ul>
   </div>

 <div id="div1">
 <div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: from where did u get (scope) value it would be undefined on the position where u have declared it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/NQQBgQKBWEqKHxGwnI0h?p=preview

As Ajay pointed out, you'll have to associate one of your scope with template.

Comment: I tried to follow your logic and set scope like:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VJd730r20qVupdMv137v

but it seems to be missing something again

Comment: I tried to clean up and fixed some mistakes in your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/HhleQICxCpZ7LctMl8Dn?p=preview

Comment: Tosh - i am sorry for being so dummy! Thank you for enlightening me!